# Is it possible to select mysql records from a file?

Tags: mysql

I want a query that can let me select records outlined in a file.
So, for instance, my file would look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and my table would look like this:

```
People
id,name
1,bob
2,joanna
3,suzan
4,buck
5,Guy
```

I want a query something along the lines of

Select * from People p where p.id IN (MY_FILE)

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Not with mySQL, no. It's not designed to do file operations.

Comment: If you have a txt file or a csv file you can read that file, construct an array with those values and then make the query.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't operate on a flat file directly and join it to other data or use it as criteria.  You can however, load data using the LOAD DATA INFILE syntax (See  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).

With that said, a procedural serverside script in just about any language can bridge this for you easily.  Your script would read your file and load the data into an array, and then formulate your mysql query and return the results.